# Was the release date of Dark season 2 preplanned?

Tags: scheduling, dark

In the Netflix series [Dark](https://www.netflix.com/in/title/80100172), the first episode (Secrets) starts with showing the date June 21st, 2019. In the episode, Michael Kahnwald commits suicide. And the original release date of the episode was 1 December 2017.

Dark season 2 aired on 21 June 2019. So did the makers decide that they were going to release the 2nd season on the exact date as shown in the first episode of the show, before they started working on the 2nd season? Or was it just a coincidence?

Comment: I think it was preplanned because 21 June, 2019 is the date when Michael (AKA Mikkel) committed suicide and cycle started for season 1. SO season 3 will probably release on June 27, 2020, the day of last cycle

Comment: Let's wait and see ;)

Comment: @SaadAnees and it did... :)

Answer (score 4):

- Writing for season 2 started on January 2018. [*](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bd0JrxFnt7c/?taken-by=baranboodar)
- Filming for season 2 ended on November 2018. [*](https://instagram.com/baranboodar/p/Bqx9zaVhSNR/)

After that, they went into post-production and it was completed in April this year.

- The trailer with the date announcement was released on April 26, 2019 — 33 years to the day after the day the Chernobyl disaster occurred.
- You guys already figured out the connection of the season 1 release date on Michael's suicide.

At this point, we can't turn a blind eye to what's going on with their clever game here. It is not a coincidence, they are purposefully doing this.

In order to achieve this, they either have to plan this ahead and fix their production/post-production dates and go according to the plan or (I really don't want to think this as a possibility but... here we go) they happened to finish filming it right at the perfect date and decided to go for it as an impulse decision.

I really don't think this is a coincidence based on how they put everything in perfect harmony...timeline-wise.